# Why is this plane $x + 2y + 3z=0$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading this text:

[image]

and I'm confused as to how/why they made y and z free variables? Also, why is this set linearly independent?

Is it linearly independent because:

$$c_1 \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + c_2 \begin{bmatrix} -3 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

produces:
$$-2 * c_1 + (-3) * c_2 = 0$$
$$c_1 = 0$$
$$c_2 = 0$$

so the only solution is trivial. Is that why this is linearly independent?

Lastly, what does 2-dimensional mean? Is it because it has two vectors? Why is this not surprising? Do basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ have 3 vectors?

Comment: the dimension of a subspace of a vector space is the number of vectors in the basis for the subspace.

Comment: It looks like a lot of your questions can be resolved if you simply reviewed the definitions of these things carefully. Read slowly and thoughtfully.

Comment: I am asking clarifying questions and I Think it's fine to do.

Comment: I don't think my questions were clear in my text

Comment: @Jwan622 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking for the set of all points $(x,y,z)$ which satisfy the following equation

$$x+2y+3z=0$$

and we can easily show, by the definition, that the set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

To find a basis of the subspace observe that we have 3 variable and only one equation therefore we can set any 2 variables free and determine the third as for example

$$y=s \quad z=t \implies x=-2s-3t$$

therefore the subspace can be written as

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=s\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}-3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

therefore since the subspace is spanned by two linearly independent vectors, by definition, we have that the dimension is $2$, the given equation indeed represents a plane.

Therefore with reference to you questions

- yes the way you follows show that the two vectors are linearly
  independent, that is by definition $c_1v_1+c_2v_2=0 \iff c_1=c_2=0$;
  in that case we don't need to check that directly since these two vectors have
  been obtained in such way to be linearly independent; indeed they are
  in the form $(a,1,0)$ and $(b,0,1)$ and therefore by linear
  combination we can't never reduce to $(0,0,0)$;
- $2$ dimensional means that the subspace is spanned by $2$ linearly independent vectors (revise the definition of basis and dimension) and since $\mathbb{R^3}$ is spanned by the three linearly independent vectors $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$ and $e_3=(0,0,1)$ its dimension is $3$ of course; the same argument applies to $\mathbb{R^n}$ which has dimension $n$.

Comment: Doesn't this repeat the explanation given in the text?  To answer, please don't summarize the explanation that the user clearly doesn't understand.

Comment: @amWhy I like to write the full explanation to better present the concepts. I'm awaiting for a reply form the OP in order to review if necessary the answer. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: What you wrote is merely a paraphrase of the very text the asker seems to not understand (and you failed to cite the text as your source of paraphrasing).  So how about *vary the words*, provide another example, explain what is meant by "free variables"... don't just spit out exactly the work that the asker is confused with.  So no, you didn't better present anything than the text did, and the text didn't work for the OP.  So, are you simply going to keep spitting out the order and presentation of the text, or try to actually test your ability to teach?

Comment: @amWhy I'm simply trying to help a person to understand the concepts and also to understand better the concepts by myself. If it is merely a repetition of the OP he can ask for further clarifications or ignore that. I don't see any problem. Of course if you don't like my answer can downvote it and/or vote to delete it. I must accept that. Those are the rules here. Thanks again! Bye